# Second Ajax Request problem in IE

Tags: php, javascript

```
    var xmlhttp;

    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
    {   // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else
    {   // code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }



    xmlhttp.open("GET" , "rajax_calls.php?"+form_data , true);
    xmlhttp.send();

    // alert(xmlhttp.responseText);

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
    {
        if ( xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200 )
            sel_2.innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;    
    }
```

Hi,
I am wrting this code in JS , plus i am also sending one more ajax request similar to the one above, but the second request does'nt seem to be sending response in IE, while it is working fine in firefox.Also, to mention i am using seperate objects for the two requests.
The first response is coming properly in both IE,firefox.I am using IE7.

Comment: Are you getting any response at all? (i.e. is the onreadsystatechange called with other values)?

Answer (score 0):

you need to create object for every request

```
function req() {
    var xmlhttp;

    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
    {   // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else
    {   // code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    return xmlhttp;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ajax complete processing if and only if it gets this combine state

```
xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200
```

you can check it but putting alert

```
alert(xmlhttp.readyState +'  '+ xmlhttp.status);
```

may be this will help you..

even i think code should be like

```
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
{
    if ( xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200 )
        sel_2.innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;    
}
xmlhttp.open("GET" , "rajax_calls.php?"+form_data , true);
xmlhttp.send();
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather use Prototype or jQuery, then you don't have to worry about things like this, even though it is good to understand the underlying code.
with prototype:

```
new Ajax.Request('rajax_calls.php', {
    parameters: formdata,
    method: 'get',
    onComplete: function(t) {
        //alert(t.responseText.strip());
        // you can do another request here if you want...
        sel_2.innerHTML=t.responseText.strip(); 
    }
});
```